# Prevent button from continuously firing while being held

Tags: javascript, controls, dom-events

I am trying to prevent specific buttons from continuously firing but have had no luck with any of my methods. I've tried several suggestions/answers from other stackoverflow posts but none have worked. I currently have a controller and for my left/right buttons I don't care if they repeat but for my jump button I do not want to be able to hold the button and have the character keep jumping. The closest I got to making this work was by using a Map and setting the button to it but unfortunately on `keyup` the character would also jump. Here is my current code:

```
class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.left  = false;
        this.up    = false;
        this.right = false;
        this.down  = false;
        this.pressed = {};

        let keyDown = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = true;
           
            if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                if (this.pressed[e.code] === false) { return }
                else {
                    this.pressed[e.code] = false;
                    this.up = true;
                }
            } 
        }
        let keyUp = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = false;
            if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                this.pressed[e.code] = true;
                this.up = false;
            }
        }
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
   }
   
}
let controller = new Controller();
```

and some alternates that I've tried also

```
        this.pressed = false;
        let keyDown = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = true;
            console.log(controller.pressed)
            if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                if (!this.pressed) { return }
                this.pressed = false;
                this.up = true;
            } 
        }
        let keyUp = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = false;
            if (e.code === 'ArrowUp') {
                this.pressed = true;
                this.up = false;
            }
        }
```

```
       this.pressed = false;
       let keyDown = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = true;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = true;
            if (!this.pressed) { 
                this.pressed = true;    
                if (e.code == 'ArrowUp') { 
                    this.up = true;
                }   
            } 
        }
        let keyUp = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowLeft')  this.left = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowRight') this.right = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowDown')  this.down = false;
            if (e.code == 'ArrowUp') {
               this.pressed = false;
               this.up = false;
            }
        }
```

Logically I feel as though these should work but they don't. And in case it matters my character jumps based on this

```
if (controller.up && !this.jumping) {this.vy -= this.speed * 60; this.jumping = true;}
```

I've probably tried doing this at least 10 different ways and the closest I got was my character jumped twice before stopping (while holding arrowup).

EDIT: this gives 2 jumps then stops. Can anyone explain why he jumps twice before stopping?

```
this.keySet = new Set();

        let keyDown = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowUp') {
                if (this.keySet.has(e.code)) { this.up = false } 
                else { this.keySet.add(e.code); this.up = 'keydown' === e.type }
            }            
        }
        let keyUp = (e) => {
            if (e.code == 'ArrowUp') { this.keySet.delete(e.code); this.up = false }            
        }
```

Comment: `let controller = new Controller()` may be firing many times which creates many instances of `Controller` while each controller creates new `keydown` event listener.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be a thing. When using a class I have to create an instance of it by doing that otherwise I'd have no controller at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can [throttle](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) the function

The way throttling works is when you call a function, it will execute the function like normal, but on subsequent calls it won't run again until enough time has passed since the last attempted execution.

Lodash has an implementation, but you can find versions of this all over the internet: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. There should be a way to accomplish this through a controller function without throttling.